# Set portlet as highlighted on add application panel

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Liferay 6.2 CE

How exactly can one go about to set a portlet to show up on the highlighted category on the add application panel? I've been searching for hours, without any luck.

Have tried to define category name as "Highlighted", but it just creates a new one with the same name.

The main goal is just to have my own portlets sit on the top of the rest.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure the following settings (here with the defaults) in your `portal-ext.properties`:

```
##
## Dockbar Portlet
##

#
# Set the portlet ids that will be shown directly in the "Add Application"
# menu.
#
dockbar.add.portlets=56,101,110,71
```

Here you see that Liferay has the habit of numbering all the core portlets. Your own portlets ids will be constructed from their plugin name and the portlet id, e.g. the *AmazingApp* portlet that is deployed in the webapplication *my-great-custom-plugins-portlet* will have an ID of *amazingapp_WAR_mygreatcustompluginsportlet* (or similar). How can you find this out by yourself? Add it to the page, then choose "Look and Feel" and "Advanced Styling" - this will show the HTML id for your portlet, of which you can easily extract the actual portlet ID to use for `portal-ext.properties`.